# 'Unexpected token { at Function (<anonymous>)' error seen while running iteration on .pug

Tags: angularjs, pug

I want to display an array of strings via pop up screen when an option is clicked. I have created Modal service and passing the elements.
Modal Service:

```
module.exports =
  function PopupModalServiceFactory($uibModal) {
    var service = {}

    var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $uibModalInstance, data) {
      $scope.data = data

      $scope.ok = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.close(true)
      }

      $scope.cancel = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel')
      }
    }

    service.open = function(data) {
      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        template: require('./popup-modal.pug'),
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        size: data.size,
        animation: true,
        resolve: {
          data: function() {
            return data
          }
        }
      })

      return modalInstance.result
    }

    return service
  }
```

Calling function:

```
$scope.testFunction= function() {
    var updateMessage= ['1) This is Message 1111','2) This is message 2', '3) This is message 3'];
    PopupModalService.open({
      title: 'This is Title',
      details: updateMessage,
      cancel: false
    })
    
  }
```

popup-Modal.pug file

```
 .modal-header
    h4.modal-title.text-info
      i.fa.fa-info-circle
      .button-spacer
      span(translate) {{data.title}}   // Displays Title properly

  .modal-body
    label.control-label
      ul 
        each val, index in  {{data.details}} //Error Displayed here
         li= index + val
```

Error Displayed:

```
ERROR in ./Documents/.../app/components/stf/common-ui/modals/popup-modal/popup-modal.pug
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /home/superadmin/Documents/.../app/components/stf/common-ui/modals/popup-modal/popup-modal.pug:23

    21|     label.control-label
        22|       ul 
      > 23|         each val, index in  {{data.details}}
        24|          li= index + val
        25|         
        26| 
    
    Unexpected token {
        at Function (<anonymous>)
```

span(translate) {{data.details}} will display the complete string with brackets but for 'each' loop its not taking the value. If i hardcode the array of string in .pug file , the list is displayed properly. Any insight into this issue would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used angular with pug before, but I suspect the issue is that interpolation shouldn't be used within a Pug `each` loop declaration. Try changing that loop to the following:

```
ul 
  each val, index in data.details
    li= index + val
```